# EF Core 2 Add-Migration Error : The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-migrations, ef-core-2.0

The error looks as following-
[image: Add-migration error]

I have tried a few things such as-  restarting visual studio, cleaning and rebuilding solution, reinstalling EF Core Nuget Packages etc. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Did it work at some point in the past?

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes. It did.

Comment: See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9891)?